# Session arraylist overwritten when new product added

Tags: asp.net, .net

My goal is to create a shopping cart which, when a link is clicked, it should create a new product class containing all the product details. I've got it creating a new product class when the query string is passed through to the shopping cart page, however it seems to get overwritten if I try to add new products to it (which requires leaving the shopping cart page)

I've spent days searching for an answer and have tried everyone I've found but none seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code behind for the shopping cart page:

```
Partial Class ShoppingCartPage
Inherits Page
Dim shoppingCart = New ArrayList() 
Dim shoppingCartSession As String


Private Sub ShoppingCartPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsNothing(Session("shoppingCartSession")) Then
        shoppingCart = New ArrayList()
    End If
    shoppingCart.Add(New Product(Request.QueryString("ProductCode"), Request.QueryString("ProductName"), Request.QueryString("Category"), Val(Request.QueryString("Price")), Request.QueryString("Description")))
    Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
    Me.TextBox1.Text = shoppingCart.Item(0).ToString & " count: " & shoppingCart.Count

End Sub

End Class
```

I tried to have the global variable set to

```
Dim shoppingCart = Session("ShoppingListSession")
```

However it gives me this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Session state can only be used when
>   enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or
>   in the Page directive. Please also make sure that
>   System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is
>   included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>` section in
>   the application configuration.'

I get this error even though I've got `sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"` in my web config and `enableSessionState="true"` on both of the applicable pages.

Comment: I've also checked my IIS settings and session state is set to true

Comment: Ok so that error goes away if I put the line inside the page load subroutine. Doesn't help make the solution work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seemed to have fixed it. I added the current session back into the array when i go back into the shopping cart page.

```
Private Sub ShoppingCartPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (IsPostBack) Then
        If Not (Request.QueryString.ToString().Length.Equals(0)) Then

            If Session("shoppingCartSession") Is Nothing Then
                shoppingCart = New ArrayList()
                shoppingCart.Add(New Product(Request.QueryString("ProductCode"), Request.QueryString("ProductName"), Request.QueryString("Category"), Val(Request.QueryString("Price")), Request.QueryString("Description")))
                Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
            Else
                shoppingCart = CType(Session("shoppingCartSession"), ArrayList)
                shoppingCart.Add(New Product(Request.QueryString("ProductCode"), Request.QueryString("ProductName"), Request.QueryString("Category"), Val(Request.QueryString("Price")), Request.QueryString("Description")))
                Session.Add("shoppingCartSession", shoppingCart)
            End If
            Me.TextBox1.Text = shoppingCartSession
            End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the following line

> Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart

you are assigning the shoppingCart field to your session item and that field is created each time you navigate to your page so it is overriding your session data, so 
you can try something like that (just add directly to your session item)

```
Private Sub ShoppingCartPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsNothing(Session("shoppingCartSession")) Then
    shoppingCart = New ArrayList()
    Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
    End If
Session("shoppingCartSession").Add(New Product(Request.QueryString("ProductCode"), Request.QueryString("ProductName"), Request.QueryString("Category"), Val(Request.QueryString("Price")), Request.QueryString("Description")))
Me.TextBox1.Text = shoppingCart.Item(0).ToString & " count: " & shoppingCart.Count
```

**Hope this can help**

Comment: Didn't fix it, that's adding a new product to the session, not the arraylist which I then need to send into rows in a new data table. I changed the session objects to be .add instead of assigning the arraylist but it still didn't add more than one item

Comment: the problem in the arraylist not in the session, so why do you need the session object

Comment: Because I need to be able to go to other pages and add more products to the cart without losing the previous objects

Comment: i think there is something missing between us, depending on the current solution you can consider your session object is the shopping cart and you add more items to it from different pages. there is no problem in that